# How to show that this set is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For an open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, let $K_j$ be the set of points $x$ of $\Omega$ such that $\text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)\geq1/j$ and $|x|\leq j$.

**Question** : Why is $K_j$ closed ?

*Thoughts* : Letting $f(x):=\text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)$, I see that $K=\Omega\cap f^{-1}([1/j,\infty))\cap \overline{B(x,j)}$.  I know $f$ is continuous (in fact even Lipschitz) so  $f^{-1}([1/j,\infty))$ is closed, but $\Omega$ is open so I can't conclude that $K_j$ is closed this way.

Comment: Hint: if you replace $\Omega$ with its closure, will $K_j$ be different?

Comment: @JankoBracic No indeed, since, in general, in a metric space $X$, we have that for all $E\subseteq X$, $x\in\overline{E}$ if and only if $\text{dist}(x,E)=0$. So in this case $\text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)=0\Leftrightarrow x\in\overline{\partial\Omega}=\partial\Omega$ hence $f^{-1}([1/j,\infty))$ contains no point in $\partial\Omega$ and taking $\overline{\Omega}=\Omega\cup\partial\Omega$ isntead of $\Omega$ in the intersection will still equal $K$. Is this what you had in mind ?

Comment: Yes, you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ be an arbitrary accumlation point of $K_j$.

$\forall \varepsilon >0 , \exists x\in K_j $  s.t $ x\in B(y,\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |y| \leq j+\varepsilon $   and  $\mathrm dist(y,\partial\Omega)\geq 1/j-\varepsilon$

let $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0 , |y|\leq j$ and  $\mathrm dist(y,\partial\Omega)\geq 1/j$

Hence , $y\in K_j \Rightarrow K_j $is closed

Comment: Nice. So you show $K$ is closed by showing that $K'\subseteq K$. When you let $\epsilon\to0$, it should be $\text{dist}(y,\partial\Omega)\geq1/j$ and not $\text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)\geq1/j$.

Comment: @Guest Exactly,thank you!